# Minimal mvc references from nuget in Web Api project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rest, asp.net-web-api, nuget

Got a clean Web api project where I want to put my Rest services.

Lets say I would like to reference System.Web.Mvc. Trying to add it through Nuget seems to give a LOT of other references. For example Razor!

Does it exist any minimal mvc Nuget package?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend [Web API empty template extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a989a149-4bc3-4292-ac8a-5101ee1722d7). It basically provides only the structure.

There is also a tutorial [on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615805/Creating-a-Clean-Minimal-Footprint-ASP-NET-WebAPI).

Here is an image of generated project (taken from code project):

[image]

I've used this extension and it fits quite well into my needs (rest services as an API, and no UI pages).

Comment: Thanks Joel. The tutorial you mentioned is actually the tutorial I'm following. And I used exactly the that Empty Web Api from visual studio gallery. But furter down in the tutorial John Atten mention the FilterConfig. You can see that he's using System.Web.Mvc. So I thought, lets use Nuget and download it. Schabadom! A huge amount of mvc stuff gets downloaded and my Empty web api is suddenly not so empty anymore.

Comment: True, some MVC references are needed. You don't get unwanted stuff like razor, though. So, I think it's better than the default WebApi project :)

Comment: Can you give me the Id for the package you have found. I keep on getting Razor

Comment: You said that you are following the tutorial. I did the same and I got none of those dependencies. Can you reproduce what you did/install in order to get those references back?

Comment: Finally answer: The Empty  Web API empty template extension exists in VS2013 or in Visual Studio Gallery for VS2012